# Difference between creating a pointer with 'new' and without 'new' apart from memory allocation?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory

What is the difference between these pointers?

I know that this one is going to be stored on the heap, even though a pointer is only 8 bytes anyways, so the memory is not important for me.

```
int* aa = new int;
aa = nullptr;
```

and this one is going to be stored on the stack.

```
int* bb = nullptr;
```

They both seem to work the same in my program. Is there any difference apart from memory allocation? I have a feeling that the second one is bad for some reason.

2) Another question which is somewhat related:
Does creating a pointer like that actually take more memory? If we take a look at the first snippet, it creates an int somewhere (4 bytes) and then creates a pointer to it (8 bytes), so is it 12 bytes in total? If yes are they both in the heap then? I can do this, so it means an int exists:

```
*aa = 20;
```

Comment: Both of those pointers are going to be stored on the stack. The difference is the first one actually points to something (an `int` on the heap) and the second one doesn't point to anything (you can't use it without causing undefined behavior).

Comment: Doing `int* aa = new int; aa = nullptr;` in sequence leaks memory. Except for the leak, it's no different than `int* aa = nullptr;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pointers are integers that just indicate a memory position, and a type (so they can only point to variables of that type).

So in your examples, all pointers are stored in the stack (unless they are global variables, but that is another question). What they are pointing to is in the heap, as in the next example.

```
void foo()
{
    int * ptr = new int(42);

    // more things...

    delete ptr;
}
```

You can have a pointer pointing into the stack, for example, this way:

```
void foo()
{
    int x = 5;
    int * ptr = &x;

    // more things...
}
```

The '&' operator obtains the memory position of the variable *x* in the example above.

`nullptr` is the typed equivalent to old `NULL`. They are a way to initialize a pointer to a known and secure value, meaning that they are not pointing to anything else, and that you can compare whether they are NULL or not.

The program will accept pointers pointing to the stack or the heap: it does not matter.

```
void addFive(int * x)
{
    *x += 5;
}

void foo()
{
    int x = 5;
    int * ptr1 = &x;
    int * ptr2 = new int(42);

    addFive( ptr1 );
    addFive( ptr2 );
    addFive( &x );

    printf( "%d\n", *ptr1 );
    printf( "%d\n", *ptr2 );

    // more things...

    delete ptr2;
}
```

The only difference is that the C runtime will keep structures telling how much memory has been spent in the heap, and therefore storing variables in the heap comes at a cost in performance. On the other hand, the stack is always limited to a fixed amount of memory (relatively small), while the heap is much larger, allowing you to store big arrays, for example.

You could take a look at [C-Sim](http://jbgarcia.webs.uvigo.es/prys/), which simulates memory in C (disclaimer: I wrote it).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I understand it better now. Am I right in the second part of my question 2) ? Does that line of code require 12 bytes?

Comment: Basically 8 bytes on the stack and 4 on the heap?

Comment: In an 64bits architecture which uses 8bytes for pointers and 4bytes for integers, yes, your assumptions are correct.